# How to fix "cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object" error

Tags: python

So working on a short piece of code that I had to fix, a sequential model with LSTM to predict the number of car sales based based on an input sequence.
But I'm getting the following error in my function to split the data:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Documents\AI assignment\a2.py", line 34, in <module>
    X, y = split_sequence(values, n_steps)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

The code I'm working with:

```
from numpy import sqrt
from numpy import asarray
from pandas import read_csv

# split a univariate sequence into samples
def split_sequence(sequence, n_steps):
    X, y = list(), list()
    for i in range(len(sequence)):
        # find the end of this pattern
        end_ix = i + n_steps
    # check if we are beyond the sequence
    if end_ix > len(sequence) - 1:
        return

    # gather input and output parts of the pattern
    seq_x, seq_y = sequence[i:end_ix], sequence[end_ix]
    X.append(seq_x)
    y.append(seq_y)
    return asarray(X), asarray(y)


# load the dataset
path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/monthly-car-sales.csv'
df = read_csv(path, header=0, index_col=0, squeeze=True)
# retrieve the values
values = df.values.astype('float32')
# specify the window size
n_steps = 5
# split into samples
X, y = split_sequence(values, n_steps)
```

I've taken a look at a few suggestions I've found already but none have seemed too relevant to what I'm working on right now.

Comment: Note that you must provide a [mre] that is __minimal__ -- remove any parts of your code that aren't relevant to your problem. Often, you'll find that this process of elimination helps you figure out the problem without even having to ask on SO. In your case, all of the code after the call to `split_sequence()` was irrelevant to your problem, so I removed it.

Comment: Thanks Pranav, not very familiar with SO so you're keeping me right.

Comment: You should also read [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Step through your code and see what it does. You will find that your function returns `None` because it enters the `if end_ix > len(sequence) - 1:` block where you `return` nothing. Since `None` is not iterable, it cannot be unpacked into `X` and `y`. ...

Comment: ... You have two options: 1. Assign the return value to a _single_ variable first, and then unpack it if it is not `None`. 2. Always return two values from your function, so in this case `return None, None`, but be sure to check the returned values before you move forward with processing them.

Comment: What else do you want to happen `if end_ix > len(sequence) - 1:`?

Comment: I didn't need to return anything, so with the advice of a friend I changed it to Break and with the proper indentation I've been able to move past that.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly you were asking here or what you want that particular part of your code to do. Your question was in dumb words "Here code, here error, no work plz fix." You got your answer on why that error occurs and what you need to do to fix it and you simply downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

On this line:

```py
# check if we are beyond the sequence
if end_ix > len(sequence) - 1:
    return
```

You return, but you don't return any data. Therefore, Python returns `None`. In the error you specified, it says:

```
    X, y = split_sequence(values, n_steps)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

What's happening here is that you are trying to assign the value `None` to `X` and `y`, but in order to assign a value to 2 variables you must pass a tuple. This is correctly done on the last line of your function:

```py
return asarray(X), asarray(y)
```

What this is actually doing is the following:

```py
X, y = (asarray(X), asarray(y)) # Tuple value
```

TLDR: To assign multiple values to multiple variables, you need to use a Tuple (`asarray(X), asarray(y)`) and not a `None` value (you must return a value from the function).

Answer (score -1):

end_ix and values will take the values 112 and 107. This will cause `return` where nothing is passed.

Unpacking a single value in a tuple causes the error.